# How do I load a python module before pip?

Tags: python, pip

I have a module that adds a metapath finder to the metapath, so it affects how modules are imported and how distributions are found.  Normally, I use `usercustomize.py` to load this finder, so it happens before any other module is loaded.

If I invoke pip with:

```
python3 -m pip ...
```

it works fine and it includes my metapath finder.  The problem is that I would like to test a new version of the metapath finder without installing it in `usercustomize.py` first.

I can use the `-s` switch to suppress `usercustomize.py`, but how else can I get my module to load before calling `pip`? I know that I could write a script that loads whatever I want and then calls pip as a module, but that's not supported by pip, and I don't want to deal with it breaking down the road.

Is there any way that I can suppress `usercustomize.py`, load my own module, and then run `pip`?

Comment: Maybe create a new virtual environment for testing? You could create either `sitecustomize` or `usercustomize` in this case.

Comment: That's ultimately what I had to do.  I think it's a little clunky, but it works.